# ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2019, http2

I faced this error when starting an asp.net with react on local host

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is by uninstalling updates

1- go to check for updates
2- Press view update history
3- press uninstall Updates and uninstall kb5003637 and kb5003537 and kb5003690
maybe some of them will not be installed but uninstall the available ones then restart the laptop and start visual studio or the IDE again

Comment: I am glad to hear that your problem has been solved, you can click '✔' to mark your reply as the accepted answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.